# Can I access the skipped "parent" of SelectMany when using dotted syntax in Linq?

Tags: c#, linq

In query syntax I can write

```
var greendoorsWithRooms = from room in house.roooms
from door in room.doors
where door.Color = green
select new {d=door,r=room}
```

Is there a way I could achieve the same with dotted syntax?

```
var greendoorsWithRooms = house.rooms.SelectMany(room=>room.Doors)
     .Where(door=>door.Color==green)
     .Select(door=>new{ <room is not in scope> }
```

I am teaching some non-programmers to use LINQPad against a proprietary object model so that we don't have to create GUI around every odd case. It would be beneficial if they didn't have to learn query syntax. Presently, I've supplied snippets solving this using foreach, but the question still comes up once in a while.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

This is also possible:

```
house.rooms.SelectMany(room => room.Doors.Where(door => door.Color == green),
   (room, door) => new { r = room, d = door })
```

It's [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534631.aspx) overload of `SelectMany`.

Comment: I believe you need to switch door and room parameters on second line so that the first parameter is the source and the second is the collection. `(room, door) => new { d=door,r=room })`

Comment: I quite like `house.rooms.SelectMany(r=>r.Doors,Tuple.Create).Where(t => t.Item2.Color ==green)`. You could put the `where` clause in a few different places, of course.

Comment: This is a great question and a great answer.  But man, reading the signature of that method in the msdn docs is a bit crazy!

Comment: @user74754 and add some expression sauce to it: https://msdn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/library/windows/hardware/bb548658(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 19):

All LINQ queries are converted by the compiler into method (dotted) syntax. Query notation is just syntactic sugar.

In the [C# language specification](http://download.microsoft.com/download/3/8/8/388e7205-bc10-4226-b2a8-75351c669b09/CSharp%20Language%20Specification.doc), the translation of "from x1 in e1 from x2 in e2" is explicitly called out on page 211.

```
from x1 in e1 from x2 in e2
```

becomes

```
from * in (e1).SelectMany(x1 => e2, (x1, x2) => new { x1, x2 })
```

Following the cookbook then, your example would be

```
from * in house.rooms.SelectMany(room => room.doors, (room, doors) => new { room, doors })
```

and then you would complete the conversion to dotted notation by adding `Where` and `Select` clauses. In fact [the documentation for `SelectMany`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534631.aspx) gives your query as an example!

```
var query =
    petOwners
    .SelectMany(petOwner => petOwner.Pets,
                (petOwner, petName) => new { petOwner, petName })
    .Where(ownerAndPet => ownerAndPet.petName.StartsWith("S"))
    .Select(ownerAndPet =>
            new
            {
                Owner = ownerAndPet.petOwner.Name,
                Pet = ownerAndPet.petName
            }
    );
```

You just have to change "owner" to "room" and "pets" to "doors" and change your filter condition.

Answer (score 2):

Not ideal, but you could always use anonymous types in `SelectMany`:
`var greendoorsWithRooms = house.rooms.SelectMany(room=> new { Room = room, Doors = room.Doors})      .Where(roomAndDoors=>roomAndDoors.Door.Color==green)      .Select(roomAndDoors => ...`

Comment: This is pretty much what the compiler turns the query syntax into under the covers. +1